# mensaje de error personalizado desde formulario de asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

hola gente como están soy nueva en este foro mucho gusto a todos quería hacerles una duda vieran que estoy haciendo un programa en asp.net core MVC y me gustaría mostrar mensajes de error personalizados básicamente mi código consiste en esto. en otras partes de mi codigo funciona bien el las alertas de swal pero aqui nose que pasa.

mi controlador

```
    public IActionResult NuevoRegistro(NuevoCliente nuevoCliente)//se ingresa el objeto cargado de la vista nuevo registro
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)// se evalua que el modelo sea valid para almacenarlo
        {
           
            bool existe = ValidarUsuario(nuevoCliente.Cedula); //validamos si la cedula contenida en el objeto existe
            
            if (existe)// si existe el usuario ya fue registrado
            {
                ViewBag.result = "Cedula ya Existe.";
                return View();
            }//sino procedomos almacenar

            Almacenamiento.clientes.Add(nuevoCliente);

             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //redireccionamos a la vista del homeController
                       
        }
        return View();
    }
```

cómo ven Aqui le paso un texto al ViewBag y este es mi vista y el botón

```
       <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" onclick="return validarUsuario()" value="Crear Usuario" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Regresar</a>
            </div>
           
        </form>
        
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts{

    <script>

        function validarUsuario() {
            if (ViewBag.result != "") {
                swal("Error", "Id ya Existe!", "error");

                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>

}
```

pero pasa que no reconoce el método y nose que estaré haciendo mal porque como ven es bastante simple, toda la Programacion funciona bien, el problema no es que no entre al if donde está el ViewBag, el problema es que de plano no me muestra la alerta pero nose que estare haciendo mal.

Comment: No funciona porque estás usando Razor (De C#) en zona de Javascript. Para que te ahorres dolores de cabeza y tengas un buen fundamento del framework de MVC con C#, aquí tienes este workshop: https://youtu.be/6LZG76aLykY Aunque es de versiones anteriores, los conceptos son los mismos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Estas mezclando elementos que se ejecutan en el servidor con otros elementos que se ejecutan en el cliente.

Prueba cambiar tu último código por esto

```
@section Scripts{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.result)) {
       <script>swal("Error", "Id ya Existe!", "error");</script>
    }
}
```

En este código el if se ejecuta en el servidor, y si cumple la condición retorna un página con el código

```
<script>swal("Error", "Id ya Existe!", "error");</script>
```

Caso contrario la página resultante no lleva ningún script

Comment: hola buenas , si ya funciona pero parece que sin importar que, el codigo se ejecuta pero no entiendo porque lo hace

Comment: @LiulinContreras Aun que no exista error, el código se ejecuta????

Comment: si claro, se ejecuta porque cuando yo ingreso un usuario y luego ingreso otro con el mismo id , alli es cuando aparece la alerta, pero aun sin meter un usuario solo entrando a la vista swal se ejecuta , entonces nose si tienes algun consejo

Comment: @LiulinContreras Me parece que el problema puede estar en el IF, actualicé mi respuesta y puse if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.result)) en vez de ViewBag.result!="", favor prueba y me avisas